# Does land count as a colored permanent?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I cast All is Dust, does land count as colored permanents?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lands are colorless:

> 202.2b Objects with no colored mana symbols in their mana costs are colorless.

Comment: yes except Dryad Arbor.

Comment: @Fallender Yes, also except with Painter's Servant or Ambush Commander or Life and Limb or… In my answers, I assume that there are no other effects or objects than the ones specified in the question that could change my answer.